# MySQL query printing double records

Tags: php, mysql, double

All recorders in `sales` & `purchase` table are only entered Once. I have checked it carefully. However I wish to combine these two tables in such a way that both tables will be completely fetched. here is my query
note that `timestamp` column has mysql `DATE` format

```
Select 
    sales.ID as sid,
    sales.saleHatsh,
    sales.timestamp as sdate,
    sales.gatePass as sGP,
    sales.pname as sPN,
    sales.description as sDES,
    sales.balance as sbal, 
    purchase.ID as pid,
    purchase.purchaseHatsh,
    purchase.timestamp as pdate,
    purchase.gatePass as pGP,
    purchase.pname as pPN,
    purchase.description as pDES,
    purchase.balance as pbal 
from sales,purchase 
where sales.timestamp='2013-11-11' OR purchase.timestamp='2013-11-11'
```

here is the result of my query & `sales` & `purchase` table
[image: Query Result]
`Sales` table only have 2 recorder
[image]

Purchase table only has 4 recorder 
[image]

Comment: You have to put a join clause in your where statement what is happening is a full cartesian plan for the two tables. For your code I would say `sales.timestamp = purchase.timestamp and purchase.timestamp = '2013-11-11'`

Comment: @JorgeCampos how to add join clause in where statement ?

Comment: try 'union ".. it will combine two separate query in one result....

Comment: @Programer You need to know what link the two tables. What I show you without knowing your table structure was a join with the two date paramenters for the two tables wich was what you show. So, It appeas that you want all registries from the two tables where the timestamp is `'2013-11-11'` with the `OR` statement that you use, the database will fetch all registries from the two tables that fit to your condition and multiplies it so, as you have two registries in one table and 4 on another they will bring you 8 registries beacause either way one or other condition has been fited

Comment: @JorgeCampos well explained. Yes I want to fetch all records from these two tables where date parameter is set. In some cases one table has more records. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: So, as I said in my first comment you just have to equals the two parameters that you want in common, you where statement would be: `from sales,purchase where sales.timestamp=purchase.timestamp and purchase.timestamp='2013-11-11'`

Comment: @programer But keep in mind that for the results that you show this wont bring any results because you don't have the '2013-11-11' on the two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening there is that you are not joining those tables in any way. so you are getting all the possible matches from those tables. Looking at the columns i don't think you want to JOIN, but probably you want a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) instead:

```sql
SELECT 
  sales.ID AS id,
  sales.saleHatsh AS hatsch,
  sales.TIMESTAMP AS date,
  sales.gatePass AS GatePass,
  sales.pname AS pname,
  sales.description AS Description,
  sales.balance AS balance,
  'SALE' AS transanctionType
FROM sales
WHERE sales.TIMESTAMP = '2013-11-11'
UNION 
SELECT 
  purchase.ID,
  purchase.purchaseHatsh,
  purchase.TIMESTAMP,
  purchase.gatePass,
  purchase.pname,
  purchase.description,
  purchase.balance,
  'PURCHASE'
FROM purchase
WHERE purchase.TIMESTAMP = '2013-11-11'
```

I added a column "transactionType" for you to identify which ones are sales or purchases.

Comment: does this UNION works for the cases when there is 3 records in sales table and 4 records in purchase. i.e. can I get complete tables of specified date ?

Comment: sure. try it out. I didn't test this, but it will return only the number of rows you have in the tables, since there are no JOINs for it to create relationships

Comment: It is only printing records of purchase table here see S.S
http://www.onlineprintscreen.com/r/1378-mfine.png

Comment: It's the dates. do you have any sale in '2013-11-11'? i don't see them in your question. If you want them all, remove the where clause from the sales part of the query.

Comment: @Programer. Were you able to get what you wanted?

Comment: You are awesome :) I learn 2 new things, 
1. UNION simple syntax
2. writing query readable :)

Comment: eheh. nice.  To make the queries more readable, you can use [poorsql](http://poorsql.com)